# how to compile some code in visual studio in my MAC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm running win 7 in virtual machine in my mac (parallels).

I wrote some small code and I try to run it and I get this problem:

`C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 10\Projects\test\Debug\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`

It tells me that he can't find the path in the users.

I check and all the path exists.

what I can do now?!

**Edit:** Here's the sample code being built:

```
#include<glut.h> 

void display() 
{ 
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
  glFlush(); 
} 

void myinit() 
{ 
  glClearColor(0.,0.,0.,0.); 
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
  glLoadIdentity(); 
  gluOrtho2D(-5., 5., -5., 5); 
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
} 

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
  glutInit(&argc,argv); 
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB); 
  glutInitWindowSize(200, 200); 
  glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100); 
  glutCreateWindow("Black Window"); 
  glutDisplayFunc(display); 
  myinit(); 
  glutMainLoop(); 
}
```

Comment: This is not an **OS X** question. Please re-tag it.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a path problem, this is a linker error.

What linker is telling you is that you need an external library to complete compilation of your code (maybe you're using some function of another library and you forgot to add them in your project parameters).

Comment: it's in openGL and I add all what I need I do the same steps in my girlfriend computer (PC) and everything work great.
I add the files that I need because that I don't know what the problem.

Comment: @user1034172 : show us the code you're compiling (or a minimal snippet of code that reproduce the failing)

Comment: #include<glut.h> 
void display()
{
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 glFlush(); 
}
void myinit() 
{
 glClearColor(0.,0.,0.,0.); 
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
 glLoadIdentity(); 
 gluOrtho2D(-5.,5.,-5.,5); 
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
void main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
 glutInit(&argc,argv); 
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB); 
 glutInitWindowSize(200,200); 
 glutInitWindowPosition(100,100); 
 glutCreateWindow("Black Window"); 
 glutDisplayFunc(display);
 myinit();
 glutMainLoop();
}

Comment: @user1034172: Right click the project->properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input.  Under "Additional Dependencies", make sure to add "glut.lib", for both Release and Debug configuration.

Comment: no "glut.lib" not in the list.
but before I start I put it in this path:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib"

Comment: @user1034172 : this is not enough to have add the path, you have to specifically tell the linker which library to use, so in your case, the `glut.lib`

Comment: @user1034172 : as Mooing Duck told you, before launching any new compilation, add `glut.lib` in your additional dependencies

Comment: @user1034172 you need to write it whenever you use something from glut.lib and before you build the project.

Comment: now I get this error:
"fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glut.lib'"

Comment: what paths are you telling the linker to look in? This should be given under the -L option I believe.

Comment: it's not a path, I click on properties go to "input" under "linker" and I see some list like this 

"kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;glut.lib" 

without any path..

Comment: There's a switch/option for configuring what path to look in for additional libraries for the linker in project->properties.

Comment: I have only "Edit" and I can add only like this "glut.lib" or something like that.
and I put it and is not help me.
I search in in the input under Linker